# I am builiding my resume on Overleaf.com platform. I am encountering a problem that there is a "4" at the end of the line. I am unable to remove it

Tags: latex, overleaf

The below provided is the complete latex code.

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Jake Gutierrez
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-1pt}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.19in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.4in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
\vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
\item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
}
}

\newcommand{\classesList}[4]{
    \item\small{
        {#1 #2 #3 #4 \vspace{-2pt}}
}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
\vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
    \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.001\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \small#1 & \textbf{\small #4}\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    {\Huge \scshape Harsh Jain} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    Alwar, Rajasthan \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small \raisebox{-0.1\height}\faPhone\ +91 8769826027 ~ \href{hrsjain.hp@gmail.com}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faEnvelope\  \underline{hrsjain.hp@gmail.com}} ~
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in//}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedin\ \underline{www.linkedin.com/in/hrsjain}}
    \vspace{-8pt}
\end{center}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{Education}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
    {MBM University, Jodhpur (Pursuing)}{August 2019 - June 2023}
    {Bachelor of Technology in Information Technology (CGPA of 8.50 aggregate; 9.44 latest)}{Rajasthan, India}

    \resumeSubheading
    {Chinar Public School}{April 2017 - March 2018}
    {Class XII (83.8\%)}{Rajasthan, India}

    \resumeSubheading
    {Chinar Public School}{April 2015 - March 2016}
    {Class X (10 CGPA) equivalent to 95\% }{Rajasthan, India}
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{Experience}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
    {CodePlanet Technologies}{June 2022 - present}
    {Java Intern}{Rajasthan, India}
    \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Creating a backend + frontend internal tool to  do online shopping with ease.}
        \resumeItem{Tool and Technoligies used will be JAVA, spring-MVC, JSP and servlet }
    \resumeItemListEnd
    
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
\vspace{-16pt}

%-----------PROJECTS-----------
\section{Projects}
    \vspace{-5pt}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeProjectHeading
        {\textbf{Flight Reservation Application} $|$ \emph{Java Spring Boot, MySQL} $|$ {https://github.com/hrsjain/Flight-ReservationApplication}}
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{    An user interactive web application that allows users to book their flights and also to allow Airline Companies to add their flights.}
            \vspace{2pt}
            \resumeItem{    Created the email utility and PDF utility so that the Flight tickets and details can be sent automatically as the flight is booked. Password encoding system while logging in to enhance the security of the system.Exposed API for the Flight Check-in System to access the data.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
        \vspace{-13pt}

    \resumeProjectHeading
        {\textbf{Flight Check-in Application} $|$ \emph{Java Spring Boot, MySQL}  $|$ {https://github.com/hrsjain/FlightCheckinSystem}}
        \\
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{  A user interactive web application that facilitates check-in of passengers of the flight.}
            \resumeItem{    Integrated with Flight Reservation Application, the application accesses data from Flight Reservation Application.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%
%-----------Achievements-----------
\section{Achievements}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{ 150+ Programming questions solved with 2 badges on Data Structures and Algorithms on LeetCode. leetcode.com/hrsjain/}
        \resumeItem{Distinction in Science in International Assessment for Indian Schools, by UNSW Global, Australia which is one of the top institutes which assess students across the globe Student ID-8504, Class XII, Year 2018.}
        \resumeItem{Distinction in Maths in International Assessment for Indian Schools, by UNSW Global, Australia which is one of the top institutes which assess students across the globe Student ID-8504, Class XII, Year 2018.}
        \resumeItem{AIMUN Certification for Model United Nations Conference held in Amity, Noida with participants from all across the world demonstrating critical thinking, speaking skills, etc.}
        \resumeItem{ Management Core Team Member at Google Developer Students Club - MBM, through which we help bridge the gap between theory and practice by empowering a peer-to-peer learning environment.}
    \resumeItemListEnd
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-20pt}

%
%-----------SKILLS-----------
\section{Technical Skills}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
    \textbf{Languages}{: C, C++, Java} \\
    \textbf{Technologies/Frameworks/Libraries}{: MySQL, Spring, AWS} \\
    \textbf{Core}{: Data Structure and Algorithms, Operating System, Computer Networks, Database Management Systems, etc. }
    }}
\end{itemize}

%-----------Certifications-----------
\section{Certifications}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Data Structure and Algorithms-certified by Dmatics Technologies}
        \resumeItem{ C, C++, Java Programming Language- Certified by Dmatics Technologies}
        \resumeItem{AWS CLOUD TECH. ESSENTIALS -AWS through Coursera -BDED2WG6RM9H}
        \resumeItem{Building Modern Java Applications on AWS -AWS through Coursera -LYGNJ45TAZP6}
        \resumeItem{ RS-CIT certificate in Information Technology (by VMOU, Rajasthan)}
        
    \resumeItemListEnd
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-16pt}

%

\vspace{-16pt}

\end{document}
```

> I have attached both code snippet and the output. I was unable to attach the complete code because of the formatting issue.
> Please share your suggestions so as to remove the 4 at the end of the each project description line.

I have attached both code snippet and the output. I was unable to attach the complete code because of the formatting issue.
Please share your suggestions so as to remove the 4 at the end of the each project description line.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in looking at the output and wondering about stray 4's in your document. Your document does not compile! As long as there are error during the compilation, latex only syntax checks the rest of the document, not necessarily producing reasonable output. Fix the errors before looking at the output!

Never ignore error messages!

Two major problems:

- the definition

  ```
  \newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
      \item
      \begin{tabular*}{1.001\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & \textbf{\small #4}\\
      \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
  }
  ```

  makes no sense. You instruct it to take 2 mandatory arguments, yet you use the 4th argument inside the macro. This does not go together. Either increase the number of arguments or don't use the 4th argument inside the macro
- the definition of this macro is not the only problem, also how you use it. You neither use it with two argument, like you say how many arguments it has, you also don't use it with 4 arguments, how you define it, you use it with only a single argument!

---

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Jake Gutierrez
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-1pt}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.19in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.4in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
\vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
\item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
}
}

\newcommand{\classesList}[4]{
    \item\small{
        {#1 #2 #3 #4 \vspace{-2pt}}
}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
\vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
    \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.001\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \small#1 & \textbf{\small #2}\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\section{Projects}
    \vspace{-5pt}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeProjectHeading
        {\textbf{Flight Reservation Application} $|$ \emph{Java Spring Boot, MySQL} $|$ {https://github.com/hrsjain/Flight-ReservationApplication}}{}
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{    An user interactive web application that allows users to book their flights and also to allow Airline Companies to add their flights.}
            \vspace{2pt}
            \resumeItem{    Created the email utility and PDF utility so that the Flight tickets and details can be sent automatically as the flight is booked. Password encoding system while logging in to enhance the security of the system.Exposed API for the Flight Check-in System to access the data.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
        \vspace{-13pt}

    \resumeProjectHeading
        {\textbf{Flight Check-in Application} $|$ \emph{Java Spring Boot, MySQL}  $|$ {https://github.com/hrsjain/FlightCheckinSystem}}{}
        \\
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{  A user interactive web application that facilitates check-in of passengers of the flight.}
            \resumeItem{    Integrated with Flight Reservation Application, the application accesses data from Flight Reservation Application.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd




\end{document}
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for giving your time.  Actually, I am not latex user, I have just copied the template and inserted my data into it.  Also, as I enter my data according the code provided by you, everything works fine. Thanks for that. Just one thing,  in the achievements section of the output, i need greater line spacing. Please help me with it.

Comment: @HarshJain If you have a new question, please ask a new question